# How to Generate a List of all Input name="" fields in a form with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, input

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this, but I'm a novice teaching myself Javascript and JQuery and I just don't know enough to figure it out myself. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

I'm building a form that generates HTML emails for my company based on hundreds of different inputs entered by the form user.  Rather than copying and pasting each and every input name into a $_POST line in the form's action script to retrieve the input's data, I'm wondering if there's a way to use Javascript/JQuery to generate a list of the name="" fields from each input on the form to make this easier?

For example, from the following slice of the code, how can I automatically generate a list that contains the name values **"bottlespecial6image"**, **"bottlespecial6imagewidth"**, **"bottlespecial6imageheight"**, **"bottlespecial6imagelink"**, and **"bottlespecial6includeprice"** (with the idea that my form has hundreds (if not thousands) of inputs, so copying/pasting seems inefficient):

```
<input type="text" name="bottlespecial6image" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="bottlespecial6imagewidth" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="bottlespecial6imageheight" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="bottlespecial6imagelink" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="bottlespecial6includeprice" value="yes"  checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="bottlespecial6includeprice" value="no"  checked="checked" />
```

I apologize if this has already been covered here -- I searched around here for similar questions, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's easy to get the name attributes as an array or CSV string, but your stated reason for wanting to do this sounds a bit strange. Or - wait, are you saying you want to do this as a once off exercise to help you write the server-side code without lots of individual copy/paste operations? I would think there's some way your server-side code could be made more modular, e.g., by knowing that each `bottlespecial6` group includes an `image`, `imagewidth`, `imageheight`, etc. Are there also sets of `bottlespecial1` through `bottlespecial5` items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a serialized array to submit, you'd use jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$('form').serialize();
```

to just get the names in an array, you can map them:

```
var inputs = $('form').find('input[name]'); //all inputs with a name in the form

var names  = $.map(inputs, function(el) { return el.name });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jGW5P/1/)

Comment: This is incredibly helpful.  Thank you, adeneo!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[name='yourrequiredname']")
```

will give you list of all elements by same name